# Error installing SQL ODBC driver in windows docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker, powershell, odbc

I'm new to powershell and docker, im trying to install odbc driver for sql server in a docker container with windows as base image.  This is what my dockerfile looks like, I have assembled the contents of this file from different sources. I have the executable msodbcsql_17.msi in the current working directory in which I'm running docker build.

```
FROM python:3-windowsservercore
WORKDIR .
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
RUN  Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '-i' './msodbcsql_17.msi' '/norestart /qn /quiet /passive IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES'

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "python", "run.py" ]
```

Getting below error when i build it using docker build

[image]

Can someone please help me fix this.

Comment: Why are there single quotes around `'-i'` and `'./msodbcsql_17.msi'`?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the docker file with this and its building

```
FROM python:3-windowsservercore
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
ADD "https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/6/B/E6BFDC7A-5BCD-4C51-9912-635646DA801E/en-US/17.5.2.1/x64/msodbcsql.msi" C:/
RUN  Start-Process   'c:/msodbcsql.msi' '/qn /norestart /L*V "odbc.log"' -PassThru | Wait-Process;

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "python", "run.py" ]
```